# WinDbg/SOS: Explanation of !SyncBlk output

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg, sos

I am looking of a description of the output generated by the !SyncBlk command of SOS.

Particularly I found no useful explanation on the column "MonitorHeld". This column shows high values in a series of crash dumps.

Example:

```
0:000> !SyncBlk
Index         SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread Info          SyncBlock Owner
   44 0000000005a5c228            1         1 000000000e7a6740  2304 273   000000019f858cd0 System.Object
   48 000000000579bae8            1         1 000000000e7a72e0  2370 275   000000015f999900 System.Object
   52 000000000579b9c8            1         1 0000000011bbd3b0  1e98 295   00000000ff89fe08 System.Object
   54 000000000579b938            1         1 000000000e7a38c0  1be4 249   000000013f8aa888 System.Object
  108 0000000005a5bfe8            1         1 000000000e79f300  224c 242   00000000ff8a5828 System.Object
  110 0000000005a5c078            1         1 000000000e79ca50  2290 262   000000015f9a8020 System.Object
  112 0000000005a5c108            1         1 0000000011bb70e0  1d38 236   000000015f99e408 System.Object
  114 000000000579b620            1         1 0000000011bb93c0  1884 304   00000001bf974a90 System.Object
  124 0000000005a44d48            1         1 000000000e7a6170  2300 272   000000019f853fe8 System.Object
  146 0000000005a44688           99         1 000000000588cbf0  13e0  38   000000017f71c4f8 System.Object
  155 0000000005a44f88            1         1 0000000011bba530  2274 301   000000019f82f120 System.Object
  157 0000000005a45018            1         1 0000000011bbf0c0  2034 290   000000015f952980 System.Object
```

Can anyone explain the "99" in column "MonitorHeld"?

Has anyone a a link to a complete reference documentation of this command?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The MonitorHeld refers to how many monitors are held by that specific SyncBlk.

Each time you have contention on a lock, you'll have 1 owner held syncblk.  Each waiter on a lock holds 2.

Your 99 means that you have one object "owning" the lock, and 49 objects waiting on the lock (49x2 + 1 = 99).

The best discussion and detailed explanation of `!syncblk` I've found is [this one by Tess Ferrandez](https://web.archive.org/web/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/09/a-hang-scenario-locks-and-critical-sections.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Reed mentioned, you can use the SOSEX.dll extension's !dlk command to check for deadlocks as well.

Comment: Very interesting didn't know about this extension!

Comment: !dlk is very useful, but it doesn't find all deadlocks.

Comment: looks like sosex is outdated for .NET 4, psscor4 is the only option I've found

Comment: sosex extension is not outdated for .net 4 http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx

Comment: There is also an update now for SOSEX that can be used with .NET 4.5 -  http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXUpdatendashReadyForNET45.aspx